# How to parse this json in uitableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I am new in `iOS`. I wanna parse following `json` in my `UITableView`, but I don't know how to do that. I know `json` parsing using `NSURL`, but in this direct `json` parsing I am facing problems .please help..
here it is:

```
NSString *url = @"{\"LinkResult\":{\"0\":{\"Name\":\"Veeva - Devon1\",\"ButtonDisplay\":\"Veeva\",\"PasswordSaving\":\"Yes\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"Message\":\"No Error\", \"Identifiers\": {\"Identifier1Name\": \"Identifier1value\",\"Identifier2Name\": \"Identifier2value\",\"Identifier3Name\": \"Identifier3value\"},}}}";
```

please tell me next steps...

Comment: is it response or sent postData

Comment: @Hercules its a simple json i want to retrieve in my uitableview.
i am just putting this json in my viewcontroller so how i can further proceed ..please tell...

Comment: Ok,I am looking at...wait

Comment: yup.. but i am not fetching this json from any url.. its static written in my code ...

Comment: Which information do you want to show in your tableView?

Comment: Use SBJson for parsing json. Its simple. Search in google

Comment: @Anupdas Name,Password,Status,Message,Identifiers1,2,3 Name...

Comment: If I'm guessing correctly you have a dictionary with key `LinkResultSet` which have key value pairs of numerical numbers and the respective users. If this is static data you may want to change the structure a little bit as dictionaries don't maintain order of keys.

Comment: @Anupdas- i Din get u ...

Comment: @Durgaprasad, start to using NSJSONSerialization class given by apple. It fulfill all your requirement. Also its very easy to handle data.

Answer (score 3):

This is the structure of your JSON

```
{
    "LinkResult": {
        "0": {
            "Name": "Veeva - Devon1",
            "ButtonDisplay": "Veeva",
            "PasswordSaving": "Yes",
            "Status": "Success",
            "Message": "No Error",
            "Identifiers": {
                "Identifier1Name": "Identifier1value",
                "Identifier2Name": "Identifier2value",
                "Identifier3Name": "Identifier3value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create a json file using any online generators and add it in your project. Have a property for keeping the dataSource.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Data"
                                                        ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:nil];

    //A dictionary which will contain info all users
    self.users = dict[@"LinkResult"];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.users allKeys] count];;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSArray *sortedKeys = [[self.users allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSString *key = sortedKeys[indexPath.row];

    NSDictionary *user = self.users[key]; 

    cell.textLabel.text = user[@"Name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = user[@"Status"];

    return cell;
}
```

[Source Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestJSONTableView.zip)

Comment: Thanks a lot Anup.. what else if i wanna retrieve all the values in separate cells ??

Comment: @Deep You are welcome, with the source code you can figure out the rest. One approach is to make a custom tableViewCell to represent the data in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use the NSJSONSerialization class for this, something like:

```
NSData *json = [url dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *identifiers = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Identifiers"];
// Do stuff with the data
```

Hope that makes sense. You can pull elements from the JSON string by using:

```
[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"ElementName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your json string to NSDictionary object in order to used in tableView,below code will convert it to NSDictionary object and then you can set values accordingly by using its key value.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *jsonString = @"{\"LinkResult\":{\"0\":{\"Name\":\"Veeva - Devon1\",\"ButtonDisplay\":\"Veeva\",\"PasswordSaving\":\"Yes\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"Message\":\"No Error\", \"Identifiers\": {\"Identifier1Name\": \"Identifier1value\",\"Identifier2Name\": \"Identifier2value\",\"Identifier3Name\": \"Identifier3value\"},}}}";

    NSData *jsondata=[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsondata options:0 error:nil];

    displaydata=[[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"LinkResult"] valueForKey:@"0"];
    NSMutableArray *mutableKeys=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[displaydata allKeys]];
    [mutableKeys removeObject:@"Identifiers"];
    keys=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableKeys];

    NSLog(@"JSON DIct: %@", displaydata);
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [keys count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [displaydata valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but how to display this json data on my tableviewcell ??

Comment: @Deep You'd have to do that in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in the UITableViewController

Comment: @Deep you can replace your code easily with my code.

Answer (score 0):

to parse you could use nsdictionary like this...

```
NSData *json = [url dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *identifiers = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Your key"];
```

and to show it in tableview you could use

```
arr = [[JSONObject objectForKey:@“results”] objectForKey:@“Your key”];

// and set cell text label as -

cell.textLabel.text =[[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Your key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *url = @"{\"LinkResult\":{\"0\":{\"Name\":\"Veeva - Devon1\",\"ButtonDisplay\":\"Veeva\",\"PasswordSaving\":\"Yes\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"Message\":\"No Error\", \"Identifiers\": {\"Identifier1Name\": \"Identifier1value\",\"Identifier2Name\": \"Identifier2value\",\"Identifier3Name\": \"Identifier3value\"},}}}";

    NSData* jsonData = [url dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json is %@", json);

    NSDictionary *LinkResult = [json valueForKey:@"LinkResult"];
    NSLog(@"LinkResult is %@", LinkResult);

    for (id key in [LinkResult allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"Value for 0 index is %@", [LinkResult valueForKey:key]);

        NSLog(@"ButtonDisplay is %@", [[LinkResult valueForKey:key] valueForKey:@"ButtonDisplay"]);
        NSLog(@"Message is %@", [[LinkResult valueForKey:key] valueForKey:@"Message"]);
        NSLog(@"Name is %@", [[LinkResult valueForKey:key] valueForKey:@"Name"]);
        NSLog(@"PasswordSaving is %@", [[LinkResult valueForKey:key] valueForKey:@"PasswordSaving"]);
        NSLog(@"Status is %@", [[LinkResult valueForKey:key] valueForKey:@"Status"]);
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

Here it is friend

```
NSString *url = @"{\"LinkResult\":{\"0\":{\"Name\":\"Veeva - Devon1\",\"ButtonDisplay\":\"Veeva\",\"PasswordSaving\":\"Yes\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"Message\":\"No Error\", \"Identifiers\": {\"Identifier1Name\": \"Identifier1value\",\"Identifier2Name\": \"Identifier2value\",\"Identifier3Name\": \"Identifier3value\"},}}}";

NSArray *arrComponents = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *arrmFilter = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < [arrComponents count] ;i++)
{
    NSString *str = [arrComponents objectAtIndex:i];
    //str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@""];

    [arrmFilter addObject:str];
}

NSLog(@"Filtered array = %@", arrmFilter);
```

You Will have to do Some changes in `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString
But this vill extract JSON....
Hope this helps..

Comment: why negative points sir?
print it out in DEMO code

after inserting into array you can easily put data in TABLEVIEW

Comment: You should read JSON and NSJSONSerialization class